# What the this author mean by "guide a competitor"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this headline:

> **"Inside the Implosion of CNN+**
>
> Seen as the future of CNN, the streaming channel was suddenly killed. Its next owner, Discovery, had concerns but was constrained in guiding a competitor."

article source:

"https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/24/business/media/cnn-plus-discovery-warner.html"

I read it all through but can't understand from the article why Discovery should "guide its competitor" I mean guide to do what? is guiding to help? the text does not make it clear or I lack
some sort of business knowledge

Comment: That isn't what it says.  It's important to give accurate quotes here because the context is important in understanding it. The quote should be: "Its soon-to-be owner, Discovery, had concerns but until the deal closed, it was constrained in guiding a competitor."

Answer (score 2):

**The NY Times** has this:

> Inside the Implosion of CNN+ Seen as the future of CNN, the streaming
> channel was suddenly killed. Its soon-to-be owner, Discovery, had
> concerns but until the deal closed, it was constrained in guiding a
> competitor.

[This means that until the deal was completed, Discovery could do nothing as it was not allowed at that point to guide CNN+, which was a competitor to it. Once the deal was completed, Discovery could have done whatever it wanted to do. See below]
[...]

> And it reflected the awkward regulatory dance of two media giants
> merging even as a high-profile project hurtled toward completion.
> Discovery had some concerns about CNN+, *but was constrained from
> directly guiding one of its streaming competitors until the deal
> closed.*

[That second sentence makes much clearer]

to guide a company means to give it a direction in which to go; to provide guidance. Generally, if one company owns another that is below it, it can guide it to do this or that. guide here is like lead. lead it to do something. Show it in which direction to go.

Since Discovery didn't own it, it was not able to tell it to do anything. Then, the deal fell through.